# Calculate Angles Related to a Circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The image below shows a circle centered around $(x,y)$ and with a radius $r$.

I am able to calculate $\theta_1$ which is $\text{atan} 2(y,x)$

I require the values for $\theta_2$ and $\theta_2$ but I don't know how to calculate these values.

I tried to search Google, but I don't even know how to word the question.

[image: Diagram showing two tangents]

Comment: What did you try in finding the other? (I wonder what is atan2(y,x))

Comment: @ArcticChar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2 is a two-argument extension of the $\arctan$ function that takes in both coordinates rather than their ratio, and therefore can distinguish between all four quadrants and have a range of a full revolution rather than a half.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. So it is really a definition.

Comment: @ArcticChar I first drew a diameter across the circle which made a right angle with the black line (sorry I should have labelled the points).  But this caused the red/blue lines to intersect the circle which is not what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, provided that $r\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $$\Theta_1-\Theta_2=\Theta_3-\Theta_1=\arcsin\frac r{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\operatorname{atan2}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2-r^2},r\right)$$

And you're done.

Comment: Thank you @Saucy O'Path.  I think I understand.  If I drew a line from the center of the circle to the point at which the red line touches the circle, then that would form a right angle with the red line, and I think that's what your answer is based on.

Comment: I will put the formula into my code tomorrow to see if it fixes it. In the meanwhile please could you tell me how I should have worded my question? I could then update the title of this post.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the radius from $(x,y)$ to the tangent point. Together with the origin, this will form a right angle triangle. The hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the side is $r$, so the angle $\theta_1-\theta_2$ is given by $$\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)=\frac r{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: ...and note that $\theta_3 - \theta_1 = \theta_1 - \theta_2$, by symmetry.